# how to trigger video file download in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I'm getting a video URL from my API. here I want to download that video by using that URL. I have a button called download. when I click on that button the video should start the download in my browser.

I have searched and found some solution like placing download attribute on a tag

```
<a href="{{selectedVideo.playbackUrl}}" download>Download</a>
```

it is redirecting to the other page but it does not start downloading the video.

can anyone please help with this?

Comment: Is url  internal or external? I mean if url comes from your api or another url?

Comment: comes from API.@Çağrı

Comment: is it possible to achieve without using a tag.@Çağrı

Comment: Then u can return base64 string  to download it

Comment: I tried to host a mp4 video in my local and use your code, download is working fine. download only works for same-origin URLs, or the blob: and data: schemes. Is that the reason ? Or it is a browser reason, which browser you're using?

Answer (score 1):

Using `ngx-filesaver` we can achieve this. [ngx-filesaver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-filesaver) is angular package for `filesaver.js` and it is easy to use.

Find here this [sample stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wbkdv7)

To use it in your application follow simple steps :

1. `npm install file-saver ngx-filesaver --save`
2. Import `FileSaverModule` in NgModule (It can be `AppModule` or any other module).
3. Use below directive in template to download file

```html
<button type="button"
        fileSaver
        [method]="'GET'"
        [fileName]="'videoName.mp4'"
        [url]="'https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerBlazes.mp4'"
>Download Video</button>
```

Comment: while installing this plugin getting this error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

Comment: @sun, this error occurs because of ngx-filesaver currently uses angular 9 version, and you might be using lower version, if you are working with lower version then install `ngx-filesaver@8.1.0` or `ngx-filesaver@8.0.0`